# How can I deploy two versions of a microservice at the same time in OpenShift?

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, istio

I am following the ISTIO tutorial for Service Mesh, and I am having problems to copy one of the steps they do.

```
https://docs.huihoo.com/microservices/introducing-istio-service-mesh-for-microservices.pdf
```

They have a java application called Recommendation, which they deploy twice.

```
docker build -t example/recommendation:v1 .
docker build -t example/recommendation:v2 .
```

I have a Java application, TEST, deployed in OpenShift which I want to copy and change the version, so I have TEST-V1 and TEST-V2. How can I do it? Do I need to deploy the application twice with different Deployment.yaml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do it? Do I need to deploy the application twice with different Deployment.yaml?

Basically - yes. At the end, what you need, are two service endpoints pointing to different pods. You may place the service endpoints into the same deployment file, but for sake of robustness I'd use complete different deployment.

Comment: Ill use two different deployments then! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your commands:

```erlang
docker build -t example/recommendation:v1 .
docker build -t example/recommendation:v2 .
```

are not [deployment](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/deployments.html).
What you do is [building docker image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#build-the-apps-container-image).

This is the line to deploy your service for the first example:

```
oc apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f \ src/main/kubernetes/Deployment.yml) -n tutorial
```

and second:

> Finally, inject the Istio sidecar proxy and deploy this into Kubernetes:

```
oc apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f \ src/main/kubernetes/Deployment-v2.yml) -n tutorial
```

You ask if you need to deploy 2 times if you change version. First of all, you need to know that you are operating on [containers](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container). The `docker build` command creates a container for you that you will use later. If you create a new version of the application, you should create a new container. They are similar but not identical. That means, that are completely diffent docker images from the OpenShift / Kubernetes point of view. Every time you change the container image, you need to do deploy to Kubernetes / OpenShift. You need to do it one time for each docker image change.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer =)
Very explicative and complete. I think its too obvious im pretty new to this

Comment: @shurohige, please [react](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on answers if they are helpful.